# Echolocation visualisation (echosonar)

Tags: uv

I am working currently on a visualisation of bat's echolocation system. My goal is to make bat sending waves that reveal objects before him. I already tried with wave texture but I can't figure out how to force all object (trees, river, rocks) to have the same uv so the waves point evenly in the right direction

What I get so far
[image: What I get so far]

Desired look
[image: Desired effect]

Suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: For the distance cut-off use Boolean modifier and for the shape of the wave use multiple toruses(tori?) or shape keys or a Lattice modifier.

Comment: scene is to complex for that (particle trees for example).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

If this is the look you are aiming for, unless you need to export this somewhere else, you could achieve it just by using generated coordinates.

Simply use world coordinates for your texture. Start with *Object* coordinates, then run them through a *Vector Transform* node from *Object* to *World*.

[image]

Alternatively, I imagine your bat emitting sound waves will be moving, so instead use an external object as source for texture coordinates, like an empty, then animate its position or parent it to the bat.

[image]

In both cases just animate the Color Ramp's position parameter for the stops to achieve the "moving rings" effect.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was going for, thank you very much!

Comment: This whole thing works now, however I can't force waves to move outwards like in your example. When I animate mapping z-axis after short period of time waves begin to distort which doesn't work for me. ATM I set bat to be the OBJECT to follow in TexCoordinate and now I need waves to start moving just like yours. Any tips?

Comment: In my example I animated waves outwards by keyframing the color ramp stops position. By moving UVs you won't be able to achieve that effect I think it will eventually distort. Scaling may be closer to what you want but it will yield wider and wider gaps as scale increases